# org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm writing code to save to MySQL when the user enters a comment.
However, when I press the "add" button in comment.html, I get the error "org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException".

This error is when I type "good night".

```
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value'GoodNight';
```

In the Comment class (Entity), comment is a String.
What is the reason for this error?

**Error code**

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.demo.Entity.Comment'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'GoodNight';
```

**CommentController**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class CommentController {

    private final CommentRepository commentRepository;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String logiPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("User", new User());

        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String signup(@ModelAttribute User userNname, Model model) {     

        User user = userRepository.findByUser(userNname.getName());
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        
        List<Comment> commentList = commentRepository.findByCommentAll(user.getUser_id());
        model.addAttribute("commentList", commentList);

        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("Comment", new Comment());
        return "comment";

    }

    @PostMapping("/addComment")
    public String addPage(@ModelAttribute Comment comment, Model model) {

        System.out.println(comment.getComment());
        commentRepository.save(comment);

        return "test";
    }

}
```

**Comment**

```
package com.example.demo.Entity;

@Getter
@Setter

@Entity(name = "Comment")
@Table(name = "comment_tb")
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String comment;
    private Long user_id;


}
```

**comment.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Comment page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>[[${user.getName()}]],Hello</h2>
    <div th:each="comment:${commentList}" th:object=${Comment}>
        <div>No.[[${comment.id}]] : [[${comment.comment}]]</div>
    </div>

    
    <form th:action="@{/addComment}" th:object=${Comment} method="post">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
        <label for="comment">comment:</label> 
        <input type="text"  th:field="*{comment}">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{user_id}" th:value="${user.getUser_id()}"> 
        <button>add</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**CommentRepository**

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import com.example.demo.Entity.Comment;

public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Comment p WHERE p.user_id = :user_id")
    public List<Comment> findByCommentAll(Long user_id);
}
```

Comment: Check in your database what is the datatype for `comment`

Comment: The issue with the HTML file where Long type property gets bind String value when the JSON payload is sent to the API, the request body denies and throws 400 error.

Comment: The comment type in my database was VARCHAR.
Is it an error caused by making a mistake in my HTML (Thymeleaf)?
How can I resolve this error?

Comment: In the `Comment` entity, a field also has same name as entity. Rename the field to something else like `message`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and the problem was I had an entity that had a property named exactly the same as the entity. Seems Spring gets confused somewhere. Rename the entity OR rename the property to have a different name than the entity.

A comment on the question also provides this answer so credit to @Sujit.